# Apply master repo changes into duplicate repository

Tags: git, github

I have a git mirror according to option 1 on https://help.github.com/articles/duplicating-a-repository/ and I want to apply the changes done on the actual master.

I identified the latest commit in my repo as commit `2f7...` so I do:

```
master$ git format-patch 2f7... --stdout > fix
```

then copy `fix` into `mirror` and do

```
mirror$ git apply --check fix
error: patch failed: .travis.yml:1
error: .travis.yml: patch does not apply
error: include/univalue.h: No such file or directory
error: lib/univalue.cpp: No such file or directory
```

There are no changes in the mirror compared to the master.

How can I apply the commits after commit `XXX` in repo A into repo B?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What You probably want to do is:

1. add origin repo as remote (probably already is), lets say named "upstream"
2. checkout to YOUR latest commit/branch
3. $git rebase -i upstream/master
4. resolve merge conflicts, may be lots of them; afterward $git rebase --continue  and repeat until finished
5. $git push origin --force

after this, it will look like Your commits are done after changes in upstream. Alternatively, You can use $git merge upstream/master - it causes less work for conflict resolution, but complicates history.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't realize I could add a second remote. Now the whole purpose of "origin" makes sense to me. Better late than never. :)